# How can you render the array of an API that's inside an object?

Tags: reactjs

So I have this object which is taken from an API and I want to render the hints which are inside an array. I've tried doing it by setting an if else statement and if there's a result, to map the results hint, but that's not working as I'm getting error undefined:

```
{text: "apple", parsed: Array(1), hints: Array(22), _links: {…}}
hints: Array(22)
0: {food: {…}, measures: Array(8)}
1: {food: {…}, measures: Array(8)}
2: {food: {…}, measures: Array(8)}
3: {food: {…}, measures: Array(7)}
4: {food: {…}, measures: Array(7)}
5: {food: {…}, measures: Array(7)}
6: {food: {…}, measures: Array(7)}
7: {food: {…}, measures: Array(7)}
8: {food: {…}, measures: Array(6)}
9: {food: {…}, measures: Array(7)}
10: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
11: {food: {…}, measures: Array(6)}
12: {food: {…}, measures: Array(6)}
13: {food: {…}, measures: Array(6)}
14: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
15: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
16: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
17: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
18: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
19: {food: {…}, measures: Array(8)}
20: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
21: {food: {…}, measures: Array(5)}
length: 22
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
parsed: [{…}]
text: "apple"
_links: {next: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here is my full code where I try to render it without much luck:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function DietForm() {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('')
    const [data, setData] = useState({})


    const handleOnInputChange = (e) => {
        setResult(e.target.value)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com/parser',
        params: {ingr: result},
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'edamam-food-and-grocery-database.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': '6bc4948226msh1716c54bf80ad8dp1c8c12jsnac7a17a9e0a6'
        }
      };
      console.log(options.params.ingr)
      axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
          setData(response.data);
          console.log(response.data)
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
      });
    
    }, [result])
    
    console.log(result)
    return (
        <div>
            <form class="w-full max-w-lg">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        Breakfast
      </label>
      <input value={result} class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" id="grid-first-name" type="text" onChange={handleOnInputChange} placeholder="Search" />
      {result ? result.hints.map((data) => {
        return <div key={data.id}>{data.text}</div>
      }) : "none"}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Lunch
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Doe" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Dinner
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Doe" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-2">
  <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Snack
      </label>
      <input class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" id="grid-last-name" type="text" placeholder="Doe" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DietForm
```

Comment: so you want to render all the measures together ? or render your food details and the corresponding measures below it ?

Comment: food details and corresponding measures below

Answer (score 0):

Your result needs to be a "food"

```
const handleOnInputChange = (e) => {
   setResult(data.find(food => food.text === e.target.value))
}
```

Originally it is just the text you typed inside the input

```
setResult(e.target.value)
```

So it is undefined if you try to access anything a string doesn't have, the string pass your check because it is defined, it just doesn't have a hint property

The above code uses [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get a result or return undefined

Initialize data as an array

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

And make sure it only gets assigned an array

And as the hints object doesn't have text, change the rendering:

```
  {result ? result.hints.map((data) => {
    return <div key={data.food.text}>{data.food.text}</div>
  }) : "none"}
```

Comment: still getting same error, also getting data.find is not a function

Comment: Do the hints object has a text property? From the example you sent `0: {food: {…}, measures: Array(8)}` looks like it doesn't, is it inside the food prop?

Comment: hints object doesn't have a text property

Comment: Check updated answer, it cannot find the find method if `data` has something else other than an array, and in the rendering part, data is a hint object, so access props that are defined for it, I changed to access data.food.text, assuming food has a text prop

Comment: getting undefined all the time

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the data and not the result because you are setting the data from api response.

```
setData(response.data)
```

It should be like this :

```
{data ? data.hints.map((data) => {
        return <div key={data.id}>{data.text}</div>
      }) : "none"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// make the initial state of your data as null 
const [data, setData] = useState(null)

// iterate over the data 
{data ? data.hints.map((hint, index) => {
  return <Food key={index} hint={hint} />
}) : "none"}

// have a separate component called Food which renders the food and its corresponding measures below it
const Food = ({hint}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p> {hint.food.text} </p>

      {/*  render the measures*/}

      {hint.measures.map((measure, index) => {
        return (
          <p key={index}>{ render your measure here }</p>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```